# Limit of some random variable sequence: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\max_{1\le i\le n} Y_i}{n}$

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose that we have some infinite sequence of random variables $\{Y_i\}$. They may or may not be independent.

I wonder whether there is some existing theory or method which would deal with $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\max_{1\le i\le n} Y_i}{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without making any assumptions whatsoever, I cannot imagine that much can be said. Maybe what you're looking for is [extreme value theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory), which treats similar questions under some assumptions of independence. Also related is the [theory of large deviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviation_theory).

Answer (score 0):

In some cases this will at least converge in distribution. Suppose $Y_i$ were independent with CDF $F_Y$. Define $M_n = \frac{\max_{1\le i\le n} Y_i}n$.  The event that $M_n \le x$ is equivalent to $Y_1 \le xn, \ldots, Y_n \le xn$, and so the CDF of $M_n$ is $F_{M_n}(x) = F_Y(xn)^n$.

If we take, for example, a random variable with CDF
$$
  F_Y(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 1 \\ 1-1/x, & x \ge 1 \end{cases}
$$
The limit
$$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} F_{M_n}(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} F_Y(xn)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{xn}\right)^n
 = e^{-1/x}, x \ge 0
$$
and so $M_n$ converges in distribution to a random variable with CDF $e^{-1/x}, x\ge 0$. For other random variables $Y$ the limiting distribution depends on the shape of the tail, but the first steps for turning it into the limit CDF will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the $\{Y_i\}$ is a sequence of independent RVs distributed with common cdf $F_Y(\cdot)$ then, the cdf of $M_n:=\displaystyle \frac{\max_{1\le i\le n}Y_i}{n}$ is given by $F_{M_n}(y)=(F_Y(yn))^n$ as shown by @pokes. If $\{Y_n\}$ is a Martingale or submartingale sequence with some finite moment of order $p\ge 1$, then by Doob's inequality $$P(|M_n|\ge \lambda)\le \frac{\mathbb{E}(|Y_n|^p)}{n^p\lambda^p}$$ So as $n\to\infty$ the sequence $M_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.